# cannot get xamarin andriod project to see portable class project classes in same solution

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Environment - if you need additional information, please let me know.

Windows 10 developer laptop (latest service packs and updates)

Visual Studio 2017 15.3
.net - 4.7.02046 
xamarin 4.6.0295
xamarin.android sdk 7.4.0.19 java 1.8

I have a solution with 4 projects

1. portable class library
2. android UI
3. IOS UI
4. Windows UI

I am trying to access a class in the portable class from the android ui.  The ValidateShopLoginAsync exists in the portable class library.  The following is from the android UI project and code.

```
Boolean shopvalidated = ValidateShopLoginAsync("http://m.rometech.net/MWebService/AuthenticateUser", globalshopid, globalshoplicense);
```

The ETechX is the namespace of the portable class, yet it does not recognize it in the using.  The following is from the Android ui project and code.

```
using System;
using ETechX;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
```

I added the reference from the Android project to the portable class library.

Here is the code in the portable class library project and code snippet.  The task ValidateShopLoginAsync is listed here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Web.Http;
using HttpClient = System.Net.Http.HttpClient;

namespace ETechX
{
    class ETechX
    {
        public async Task<bool> ValidateShopLoginAsync(Uri tUri, string tShopIdentification, string tShopLicense)
        {
            var soapString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><AuthenticateUser xmlns='http://m.rometech.net/MWebService'><shopIdentification>" + tShopIdentification + "</shopIdentification><shopLicence>" + tShopLicense + "</shopLicence></AuthenticateUser></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://m.rometech.net/MWebService/AuthenticateUser");
                var content = new StringContent(soapString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                var response = await client.PostAsync(tUri, content);
                using (response)
                {
                    var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return ParseSoapResponse(soapResponse);
                }
            }

        }



       private bool ParseSoapResponse(string soapResponse)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything I have read says this should work, but I must be missing something else, that no one is telling me about in linking the android project to a task in the portable class library.

I scoured through 100's of comments on this.  Even e-mail Xamarin support.  They have yet to respond to anything I have ever sent them.  Not sure if they ever do respond.

When I get this working, it will solve a ton of issues I am having right now.  Please assist.

Comment: `class ETechX` - you need to make your class public

Comment: Jason, the class is public.  Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Hvaughan3, this is a new solution just for this project.  I do not believe copying this to another solution is the answer.  I tried this last week, assuming there was something wrong with our solution.  Could not access the web service call in one project in the solution from a class in another project in the same solution.

Comment: I can see the actual reference in the references.  Not sure if there is something I need to include in the using statement, but the only ETechX using statement it allows is ETechX.Droid, which is my current project.  Something is preventing my ETechX.Droid project from seeing anything in the other projects.  I tried accessing the models we created, but no dice.

Comment: in the code you posted the class is not marked public.  Further, ValidateShopLoginAsync is an instance method, so you need to instantiate your class before you can use it.

Comment: I must have been blind.  The class was private.  Once we changed it to public, it worked.  We had other issues creating the bool var as the return, but finally figured those out as well.  Thanks for the help and guidance.